# Get Value from Json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

hi  i  have  this    json  data

```
   var json = { "@@lang": "en-US", "ResultSet": { "@@version": "2.0", "@@lang":   "en-US", "Error": "0", "ErrorMessage": "No error", "Locale": "en-US", "Found": "1", "Quality": "99", "Results": [{ "quality": "72", "latitude": "30.778864", "longitude": "76.686648", "offsetlat": "30.778864", "offsetlon": "76.686648", "radius": "400", "name": "30.78,76.69", "line1": "30.78,76.69", "line2": "", "line3": "Mohali, Sahibzadaajit Singh Nagar, Punjab", "line4": "India", "house": "", "street": "", "xstreet": "", "unittype": "", "unit": "", "postal": "", "neighborhood": "", "city": "Mohali", "county": "Sahibzadaajit Singh Nagar", "state": "Punjab", "country": "India", "countrycode": "IN", "statecode": "PB", "countycode": "", "uzip": "", "hash": "", "woeid": "2290786", "woetype": "7"}]} };
```

i  need   second  last  value --woeid:2209786

How  can  i  get  this  value  using  json?

---

#### Update / Edit (Formatted JSON)

```
{
    "@@lang": "en-US",
    "ResultSet": {
        "@@version": "2.0",
        "@@lang": "en-US",
        "Error": "0",
        "ErrorMessage": "No error",
        "Locale": "en-US",
        "Found": "1",
        "Quality": "99",
        "Results": [
            {
                "quality": "72",
                "latitude": "30.778864",
                "longitude": "76.686648",
                "offsetlat": "30.778864",
                "offsetlon": "76.686648",
                "radius": "400",
                "name": "30.78,76.69",
                "line1": "30.78,76.69",
                "line2": "",
                "line3": "Mohali, Sahibzadaajit Singh Nagar, Punjab",
                "line4": "India",
                "house": "",
                "street": "",
                "xstreet": "",
                "unittype": "",
                "unit": "",
                "postal": "",
                "neighborhood": "",
                "city": "Mohali",
                "county": "Sahibzadaajit Singh Nagar",
                "state": "Punjab",
                "country": "India",
                "countrycode": "IN",
                "statecode": "PB",
                "countycode": "",
                "uzip": "",
                "hash": "",
                "woeid": "2290786",
                "woetype": "7"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can go through the objects with '.' operator and since Results is in array use '[]' and get the required object...
try this.

```
var val=json.ResultSet.Results[0].woeid
alert(val);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
json.ResultSet.Results[0].woeid
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use this way:

```
alert(json.ResultSet.Results[0].woeid);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
json.ResultSet.Results[0].woeid
```